# What's the best way to flatten nested XAML content to a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I've got this in my XAML:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" Content="Hello" />
```

Then I can see that the value of `MyButton.Content.ToString()` is `Hello`.

But if I've got something like this in my XAML:

```
<Button Name="MyButton">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Hello" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Then suddenly `MyButton.Content.ToString()` is `System.Windows.Control.StackPanel`.

What's the best way to effectively "flatten" the content of a FrameworkElement and looking the actual text content? So in this second case it should also return `Hello` like the first.

Comment: Either name the inner label so it can be accessed, or you'll have to write a recursive parser which can inspect each control type. Can you explain why you need this? Might help find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion

```
string fetchContentString(object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if(o is string)
            {
                return o.ToString();
            }

            if(o is ContentControl) //Button ButtonBase CheckBox ComboBoxItem ContentControl Frame GridViewColumnHeader GroupItem Label ListBoxItem ListViewItem NavigationWindow RadioButton RepeatButton ScrollViewer StatusBarItem ToggleButton ToolTip UserControl Window
            {
                var cc = o as ContentControl;

                if (cc.HasContent)
                {
                    return fetchContentString(cc.Content);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }

            if(o is Panel) //Canvas DockPanel Grid TabPanel ToolBarOverflowPanel ToolBarPanel UniformGrid StackPanel VirtualizingPanel VirtualizingPanel WrapPanel
            {
                var p = o as Panel;
                if (p.Children != null)
                {
                    if (p.Children.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if(p.Children[0] is ContentControl)
                        {
                            return fetchContentString((p.Children[0] as ContentControl).Content);
                        }else
                        {
                            return fetchContentString(p.Children[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Those are special
            if(o is TextBoxBase) // TextBox RichTextBox PasswordBox
            {
                if(o is TextBox)
                {
                    return (o as TextBox).Text;
                }
                else if(o is RichTextBox)
                {
                    var rt = o as RichTextBox;
                    if (rt.Document == null) return null;
                    return new TextRange(rt.Document.ContentStart, rt.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
                }
                else if(o is PasswordBox)
                {
                    return (o as PasswordBox).Password;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Give it a ContentControl,Panel or a TextboxBase and it should give you the first string content it finds.

in the Panel its whatever the first child leads to, in the TextBox base its the Password/Text/Document properties with some help from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#classes_that_contain_arbitrary_content

i haven't tested deeply just the 2 samples you provided but thats probably the way to go.